# Как определить входит ли геоточка(с широтой, долготой) в радиус?

Tags: геометрия, gps, картография

У меня есть скажем 2 объекта с координатами от Google карт. `Объект№1: 55.649486;37.3317788`. `Объект№2: 55.82907900000001;37.3081032`. Мне необходимо проверить находится ли Объект№1 в радиусе скажем 10 метрах с объектом №2. По какой формуле мне это высчитывать, учитывая тот факт что я не могу использовать математические операции как арксинус косинус . Не могу использовать потому что данные операции выполняются в специфической среде. У меня доступны следующие операции: + - / * ^ sqrt Также необходимо учесть что GPS заданное в градусах.

Comment: синус и косинус считать приближенно так (через ряды тейлора): https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/sine_calculator.php

расстояние вот:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508574/calculate-coordinate-from-starting-point-having-distance-and-an-angle-for-all-q

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula